# How do I get rails and mail-gpg to actually encrypt a message with actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, encryption, gnupg

I have been trying for a few days now to get Rails and mail-gpg to actually encrypt an email.  I am obviously missing something.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code...

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "applerocks@gmail.com"

  def sample_email(to_email_address)

    applerocks_gmail_com_public_key = <<-END
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1

mQENBFXI/dEBCAC93lu3MnTTJx1mTy67t11...
=bSQdF5z+byVKbSb90ogG9XfPYA==...
... Removed for security

-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
END

    Mail.new do
      to 'applerocks@gmail.com'
      gpg encrypt: true, keys: { 'applerocks@gmail.com' => applerocks_gmail_com_public_key }
    end

    @to_email_address = to_email_address
    mail to: @to_email_address, subject: 'Sample Email', gpg: { encrypt: true, sign_as: 'applerocks@gmail.com', password: 'applerocks' }

  end
end
```

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

First you have to also include your private key in `applerocks_gmail_com_public_key`, just stack it after the public key.

After that you need the receivers certificate, you can get it by doing:

```
hkp = Hkp.new
to_email_address_publ_key = hkp.search(to_email_address)
to_email_address_cert = hkp.fetch(to_email_address_publ_key[0][0])
```

Remove this part:

```
Mail.new do
  to 'applerocks@gmail.com'
  gpg encrypt: true, keys: { 'applerocks@gmail.com' => applerocks_gmail_com_public_key }
end
```

Then change end part to:

```
mail to: to_email_address, subject: 'Sample Email', gpg: { encrypt: true, sign_as: 'applerocks@gmail.com', password: 'applerocks',keys: { 'applerocks@ gmail.com' => applerocks_gmail_com_public_key, to_email_address => to_email_address_cert}}
```

I hope it helps.